# Disabling zoom on chrome trick

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll, zooming

In my web page I wanted to set the zoom at 100%.
For chrome I found this trick:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    var zoom = window.devicePixelRatio;
    document.body.style.zoom = (100 / zoom) + "%";
}
```

This will display the page with the same dimension in every zoom level. The problem is that on chrome when you change the zoom, it scrolls vertical and horizontal. 
I would like to stop this.

Comment: Thanks for this trick, it's better than nothing !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that a meta tag was invited:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                                                                 ^^^Zoom on site load
```

Just place this in head and remove your JavaScript.

To disable zoom use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: When I press CTRL + or CTRL - the zoom changes. What I want is to stop this behaviour. The javascript code I added fixes the page dimension at 100%. What I want is to stop bad scrolling when you zoom.